# How to delete blank cells and regroup not empty cells on Google Sheets column

Tags: google-sheets

You have a column, some cells have data, some are empty. How can you regroup the not empty data? example, you have this:

this

\

is

an

example

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

and you want this:
this
is
an
example

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

like alphabetical order, but in this case order like it is, but without empties

thanks!

[pd capture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZoRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=FILTER(C:C; C:C<>"")
```

and you can sort it like:

```
=SORT(FILTER(C:C; C:C<>""))
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you very much for answering my question. I really appreciate it!

To complete the issue, the best way i found to solve this was using regex
^\n
will match 

every new line      \n
that is at the beginning of the line ^